# Code pipeline getting failed at source stage when run from cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to create a code pipeline using cloud formation. My cloudformation template gets created successfully. However, the pipeline created gets stuck at the source stage itself saying the provided role does not have permission to access codecommit/s3.
The problem is that I have already given codecommit:* and s3:* policies to the pipeline role. Also I am using user permissions while running the cloud formation template and the user has admin permissions.
When I rerun the pipeline from the dashboard the pipeline runs successfully. Why is it getting failed when run automatically on getting created?

Following is the code where I am facing the problem:

```
Resources:
  
  CodePipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: 
              - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
              - events.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /

  CodePipelinePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties: 
      PolicyName: CodePipelinePolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - iam:PassRole
            Resource: "*"
            Effect: Allow
            Condition:
              StringEqualsIfExists:
                iam:PassedToService:
                  - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
                  - elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com
                  - ec2.amazonaws.com
                  - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
          - Action:
              - s3:*
              - cloudwatch:*
              - codecommit:*
              - opsworks:*
              - states:*
              - appconfig:*
            Resource: "*"
            Effect: Allow
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Roles:
        - Ref: CodePipelineRole
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties: 
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: S3
        Location: !Ref S3Bucket
      Name: SamplePipeline
      RoleArn: !GetAtt [CodePipelineRole,Arn]
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - InputArtifacts: []
              Name: Template
              Region: !Ref AWS::Region
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: S3
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: template
              Configuration:
                S3Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
                PollForSourceChanges: 'false'
                S3ObjectKey: !Sub ${NameOfArtifact}.zip
              RunOrder: 1
....
```

Comment: you definitely need to provide some source code here. And i would also recommend not typing Cloudformation directly but instead use CDK. Saves a lot of time regarding roles and permission because most of the time CDK takes care of this.

Comment: I shall try to work with CDK. For now, I have updated the query so as to add code with it. Can you please have a look at it and help me identify why the pipeline is getting failed when auto-triggered and runs successfully when I rerun it manually without changing anything.

Comment: If it runs from console, just check what is the CP role. Console will create the role for you, so you inspect it in IAM console, and check what's missing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems that I am facing the problem with inline policy within the same template here. On using this same role(with inline policy), I am able to run another pipeline. Also the same pipeline is getting executed on retrying. I have verified that no permission is being missed by me.

Comment: As you create the role, policy and pipeline in the same CloudFormation stack, maybe the pipeline is executed before the IAM policy is even created. Can you add a `DependsOn: CodePipelinePolicy` attribute to the pipeline to rule that out?